# Not able to access DOM when it is set as variable

Tags: jquery, dom, click

I have a problem:

This works:

```
$("#testView > td:nth-child(2) > i").click(function(){...
```

But this doesn't work:

```
var baseClick = $("#testView > td:nth-child(2) > i");
baseClick.click(function(){...
```

Why is that?

Comment: Have you generated  "#testView > td:nth-child(2) > **i**" dynamically?

Comment: How to do that? @burflip

Comment: Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: @burflip, I got you. Yes, I generated it dynamically.

Comment: @joojoo Something else on your page is causing the problem. You'll have to find that to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the  tag is generated dynamically.
This:

```
$("#testView > td:nth-child(2) > i");
```

Will retrieve the DOM object associated with that  tag. So,when you try to cache it in a variable doing:

```
var baseClick = $("#testView > td:nth-child(2) > i");
```

**It still doesn't exist**

The fact is $("#testView > td:nth-child(2) > i").click() will work because it will search for the *i* tag **when is clicked**, then the DOM (and your dynamically generated *i* tag) has already been loaded.

Comment: I was able to figure out. You help was great, thanks again!

Comment: In most cases yes. In some situations, `click()` neither works. If you find yourself in that situation, the best thing you can do is use `on()` directly _(click is a shorthand of on)_. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can find `on()`official documentation.